# ruby on rails mysql2::error: unknown column 'pay_status' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I converted sqlite3 to mysql on my ruby on rails project. I made sqlite3 back-up file, using rake db:dump. And I deleted and added some columns to DB. Finally, when I did 'rake db:load', I got an error

> mysql2::error: unknown column 'pay_status' in 'field list'

Actually, I deleted 'pay_status' column, but it's in sqlite3 back-up file.
How can I fix this error? Is there any way to save DB although some columns are modified?

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:load` loads the database schema from the `db/schema.rb`. So if you have dumped the schema using `rake db:schema` which essentially dumps the schema from the database to `db/schema.rb` and then made modifications to the database by deleting/adding columns, make sure you run `rake db:schema` once again, before running `rake db:load`. Otherwise, you schema file (`db/schema.rb`) will be out of sync to the actual database.